# Unknown value or absent when executing my wix MySetup. msi with

Tags: wix

The issue is that I want to launch my MySetup.msi with command line.

Here is error in Application journal

```
    Valeur inattendue ou absente (nom : ‘PackageCode’, valeur : ‘GUID’) dans la clé
 ‘HKLM\Software\Classes\Installer\Products\B476F94747628E7478C965620AB6A219’
```

English translation :

```
    Unexpected or missing value (name: 'PackageCode', value: 'GUID') in the key 
'HKLM \ Software \ Classes \ Installer \ Products \ B476F94747628E7478C965620AB6A219'
```

Here is my wix file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" Name="MySetup" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="soso" UpgradeCode="c151e7ab-b83a-445f-93b2-2ab7122ea34b">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

        <CustomAction Id="OpenExe" Return="ignore"  Directory="exeDir" ExeCommand="'@(secondMSI)'" Impersonate="yes" Execute="deferred"/>
        <InstallExecuteSequence>
            <Custom Action="OpenExe" Before='InstallFinalize'/>
        </InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="exeDir" FileSource="@(secondMSI)"/>
        </Directory>
    </Product>
</Wix>
```

Any advice please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These guys say just delete that key:

https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB60551

Comment: I don't have it anywhere.

Comment: The error message implies it's there and incorrect, or missing when it's supposed to be there. If it's supposed to be there but missing then the registry has been corrupted because that PackageCode has been used before and is being run again, perhaps because it looks like that ProductCode is installed so there should also be a PackageCode entry for it. Your registry may be damaged, so change your WiX ProductCode and PackageCode rebuild and retry.